# how to copy string from A to B?

Tags: java, string, android-studio, copy

I would like to copy astring from begin til the next found space.
the code

`input.substring(0,input.indexof(' '));`
works but only if the String in one line.
means, if the input =

`hello people`

so i get "hello" : correct.

but the Problem, if the input =

**hello people.**

**How are you ?**

so I get :

**hello**

**How**

the code should copy only the first line til a space found.

how can I fix this problem ?

Here is my code :

```
@Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int i, long l) { 

            String input = (String) parent.getAdapter().getItem(i);
            String id = input.substring(0, input.indexOf(' '));
            Toast.makeText(Favorities.this,"id = " +id,   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

I fill the listview Item like that from database : 
`arraylist.add(text1 + "\n" +text2+ "\n " +....`

Comment: Are you doing this through a loop or repeating the action somehow? Do you mind showing us just a little more of your code. Thanks

Comment: If more than one line gets processed, you must be doing it in a loop. If you are doing it in a loop, you should get exactly the output that you get. Is that not what you want?

Comment: Did you run onItemClick more than one time. Does toast.maketest somehow call onItemClickAgain?

Comment: a long text will be displayed into listview, it begins with the ID which i would like to copy it. show the code above pls

Comment: I have an Idea : i put a special character after the id like a star " * " 
so the code will find only one star. better as the space, because the text have many spaces : so i do like that :
`arraylist.add(id +" * " + "\n" +text2+ "\n " +. . .`